# Scipy find_peaks gives inaccurate base of peaks

Tags: scipy

[image: Here is the image]

Hi. The question is really simple, find_peaks does not accurately get the base of the peaks.

Is there some parameter that I could adjust, or is there a better function I could use? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nonreproducible - add data and code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.peak_prominences.html#scipy.signal.peak_prominences discusses how the left/right bases are determined. You may want to window the peak finding and see if that changes things.